# NSScrollView displaying problems in Xcode 5 after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode5

`NSScrollView` displaying `NSTableView` based on custom view (Image, checkbox and text label). When I scroll - I have lag (bug?) with redrawing rows.

Normal:[image: Normal]

Bugged after scroll: [image: Bugged after scroll]

Project (and .xib file) was updated from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5 format. I think this bug appeared after it, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Realisation of NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate protocols:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView *) aTableView {
return [arrayOfObjects count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    CMListItem *currentObject = [arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex: row];
    NSString *currentName = [currentObject name];
    BOOL currentState = [currentObject state];
    NSImage *currentImage = [currentObject getArtwork];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MainCell"]) {
        CMTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier: identifier owner: self];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = currentName;
        cellView.button.state = currentState;
        cellView.imageView.image = currentImage;
        return cellView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

`NSScrollView` not modified. 
My own table cell view - subclass of `NSTableCellView` with few additional outlets.

UPDATE: this thing helped me: set `Can Draw Concurrently` for all `NSTableView` at `On` state, then turn it to `Off` state.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, it's just an example. I've got after-images on my NSScrollView like on this image (just can't upload my own images - not enough rating).

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41688771/1.tiff - normal,

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41688771/2.tiff - after scrolling

Comment: All right than please show us how implemented the scroll view delegate methods.

Comment: I modified original post with my code, hope it will help to find the solution)
I don't have any more code, which working on this table.

Comment: Please follow the updated code below and make it correct. If it really helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have seen this problem sometimes when "Copy On Scroll" is enabled. Try disabling this option in IB (in the attribute inspector, scrollview section, behavior).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me to find a solution. Don't know why, but when I turn on "Can draw concurrently" for all NSTableView tree, this problem was fixed. But frames per second was too low, and I turn it off (for all tree). Now - good FPS, and no this lag.
Really don't know what happened, but it help! Maybe it was Xcode 4 -> Xcode 5 converting problems, maybe something else..